# Grocery stores open 24 hours a day in Jakarta Selatan

Tags: shopping, indonesia, jakarta

Are there any grocery stores that are open 24 hours a day in South Jakarta (Jakarta Selatan)? Carefour and Lotte Mart close at 22:00. People on vacation sometimes wake up in the middle of the night and want to go and get something to cook or drink...

Comment: Since Jakarta is a very big city, you may want to tell which part of Jakarta you are in.

Comment: @rudy Jakarta selatan

Comment: Experienced travelers know to travel with their own snacks to avoid such problems :)

Comment: @Doc You can not buy enough snacks for three months!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Mayo I believe this groceries do not open 24/7

- The Food Hall, Bellezza Shopping Arcade (Jalan Letnan Jenderal Supeno No. 34), Jakarta Selatan, DKI Jakarta 12210

The best you can get are

- Alfamart [Alfamart](http://static.skalanews.com/media/news/Alfamart.gif)
- 7-11
- Indomaret [Indomaret](http://stat.ks.kidsklik.com/statics/files/2012/03/13322162752075428214.jpg)
- Circle K

These groceries stores are easy to spot, even sometimes Alfamart and Indomaret are located side-by-side. Just FYI, Jakarta is very terrible when it comes to Zoning. Which means, some places (like grocery stores) are not within walking distance. At least you will need to use motorbike to get there (unless you dont mind walking for 20 - 45 minutes, roundtrip - just to buy a pack of smoke or a can of beer).

Answer (score 1):

This was harder than I thought it would be.  Eventually resorted to FourSquare, with some success.

- [The Food Hall, Bellezza Shopping Arcade (Jalan Letnan Jenderal Supeno No. 34), Jakarta Selatan, DKI Jakarta 12210](https://foursquare.com/v/the-foodhall/4bb4b007613fb7136b0894e6) - according to the foursquare tips, is open 24 hours, has wifi, and the chicken wings are recommended.
- [Swalayan 9 One One, Muara Karang Raya, Jakarta](https://foursquare.com/v/swalayan-9-one-one-24-hour/4c2e018e260bc92839e51ad3) - is stated in the description to be 24 hours.

It may well be easier once you're there - locals always know these things :)

Comment: blast, that's annoying.  Well hopefully this can help someone else in the future :)

Comment: Great :)  Enjoy it!

Comment: +1 However Fyi : Muara Karang is not in Jakarta Selatan (South Jakarta)